# Существует ли простой способ проверить кросс-доменный AJAX-запросы на стороне клиента?

Tags: javascript, ajax

привет, подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то браузер из которого можно без долгих танцев с бубном сделать кросс-доменный запрос из javascript? мне нужно для отладки тестировать AJAX-запросы на ка клиенте а из-за ограничений безопасности не получается это сделать
смотрел по этому поводу инфу на стековерфлоу и других ресурсах. многие пишут что это невозможно, некоторые что возможно, но у них не получилось такое сделать.
Есть ли простой способ для такого?

Comment: можешь написать свой браузер. Те которые за безопасность - не дадут сделать запрос

Comment: @Grundy, вроде как это возможно, если сервер настроен должным образом. А [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/4041128) пишут как заставить хром игнорировать безопасность )

Comment: @Grundy из за политики безопасности, нельзя без разрешения отправить ajax с одного сайта на другой. Нужно настраивать сервер

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, как я понял из вопроса к серверу нет доступа

Comment: @BOPOH, по идее и с остальными браузерами можно что-то подобное

Comment: @Grundy я могу ошибаться, но настраивать разрешение надо не в месте куда идет запрос, а от куда он идет. Но я могу ошибаться. Т.к. когда то я делал это...)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Сервер, который принимает запрос и отвечает, должен иметь _разрешение_ на ответ клиенту. Об этом идет речь.

Comment: @mix просто я и не помню чтобы я что то делал с сервером к которому делал запрос....

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую

Можно добавить в ярлыке запуска Chromium или его производных (Chrome, Yandex.Браузер, и т.д.) флаг `--disable-web-security`

Браузер после этого надо перезапустить

Answer (score 1):

Всю безопасность ограничивает ВАШ браузер. Если удалённый сервер (куда отправляются запросы) не поддерживает по средствам .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIf Origin "^https?://(www\.)?(firstdomain\.ru|seconddomain\.com|otherdomain\.ru)(:\d{1,5})?$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

или заголовков ответа:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin, равный *
```